# Adding Unique Modifier to an already existing model in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, dbmigrate

So I've created a model named User and email has been required on it, but I'd like to make that unique before I potentially deploy my app. I'm extremely new to rails but I've looked around for this scenario and I've only found things that allow you to add NEW columns and specify them as unique.

Any help is appreciated. I'm not sure if I should be doing this from the rails console or by adding 
`validates_uniqueness_of :email`
to my Model or what exactly. 
I've tried that and ran rake db:migrate and nothing has happened.

Thanks in advance!

A Python Guy :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you can make a field unique adding [uniqueness validation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)
You don't need to run migrations. (Im supposing that you ran migrations in order to create the **User** model/table with **email** field before)

You need to add this on your model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, uniqueness: true # :email makes reference to the user's email attribute
end
```

To test this. Open you console. (**rails c** on terminal)
Then you can create a user:

```
User.create! email: "some@mail.com"
```

Then, do this for second time:

```
User.create! email: "some@mail.com"
```

You will see a validation error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

If you execute **create** instead **create!** you won't see the Exception. Be careful with that

Comment: Oh awesome! I guess I was confused if I needed to do a db:migrate afterwards. I'm still learning about rake :3

Thanks so much for your help, your answer was extremely informative!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding validation in the model is useless if you are ever planning to use insert_all, upsert_all, etc on that table